# Appending text file to Text Area

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am reading the text file (which is always only one line). Take that and append it to the MoviesTextArea.

I have already tried moving the statement variable.

```
public static void viewMovies() throws Exception {

    File file = new File("MovieStorage.txt");

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);



    String statement = "";

    while ((statement = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println(statement);

        MoviesTextArea.append(statement);

    }

    reader.close();

}
```

stack trace:

```
at MovieShower.viewMovies(MovieShower.java:34)
    at Window1$3.actionPerformed(Window1.java:74)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Added the stack trace as requested.
I would expect the statement String to append!

Comment: You have a `nullpointerexception` tag... is that the error you're getting?

Comment: My error is " java.lang.NullPointerException"...

Comment: What is null?  Which variable on which line?

Comment: statement on the line "MoviesTextArea.append(statement)". But if I print the statement I can see that is is not nul...

Comment: Is it saying that MoviesTextArea is null?  Your code doesn't show where that is initialized, and based on your code formatting it looks more like a class name than a variable name.  Can you include the stack trace in your question?

Comment: Hmm does that clicking that button also create `MovieShower`?  Somehow you're clicking on that button and the `MoviesTextArea` you're trying to add text to hasn't been initialized yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your code shouldn't even compile--MoviesTextArea isn't defined in the snippet you posted--but it pretty much has to be null as @Luke said.

Also, MoviesTextArea starts with a capital letter so it should be a class (Instances of classes should always start with a lower case letter).  If this was the case though the class couldn't be null which would make a null pointer exception impossible.

My guess, therefore, is that it is an instance and you are not following the convention of making an instance lower case which just adds confusion to anyone trying to help.

We could help more if you could post some code that compiles, runs and shows the error. (Minimum verifiable executable example or some such)